# Recreating a tree from two flat representations

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

I have two flat representations of a tree, e.g.:

```
List 1:        List 2:

Event1      Event1
Event1      State1
Event2      Event1
State1      Event2
Event2      Event2
Event1      State2
Event2      StateI1
StateI1     Event1
Event1      Event2
Event1      Event1
Event2      StateI2
StateI2     Event1
Event2      Event2
Event1      Event2
Event2      StateI3
StateI3     Event1
State2      Event2
Event3      Event3
```

The tree is:

```
Event1 
State1
  Event1 
  Event2 
Event2 
State2
  StateI1
    Event1 
    Event2 
  Event1 
  StateI2
    Event1 
    Event2 
  Event2 
  StateI3
    Event1 
    Event2 
Event3
```

As you can see, a State can have multiple Events and States in it. Don't mind the names, they are not relevant, they just denote the type of the element.

I believe the first list is a depth-first, bottom-up traversal of the tree, and the second list is a depth-first, top-down traversal.

I need to recreate the tree from the two flat lists, that is, assign each State or Event to its parent State (or the top level). Is this possible? If so, how?

What basically happens in my code is:

```
TraverseTreeBottomUpExecutingFunction(tree, &myfunc_bottomup)

second_list = TraverseTreeTopDown(tree)

recreated_tree = myfunc_recreate_tree(second_list, optional_first_list_created_using_myfunc_bottomup)
```

I cannot change the Traverse* functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically a tree that's not binary tree can be traversed in two orders: preorder (enumerate internal nodes before the subtrees that hang from it) and postorder (enumerate internal nodes after the subtrees that hang from it). I would guess that in your problem "bottom-up" is postorder and "top-down" is preorder.

Let's assume further that all the objects can be separated from each other, i.e. they have different values or pointers. If all the objects are identical, i.e. all are identical States, you can't deduce the shape of the tree just from the traversal lists because they will look identical.

Now the thing is that if have a tree T, and preorder and postorder traversal generated node lists for it, the ROOT of that tree is the FIRST node on the preorder list and the LAST node on the postorder list. This gives you the following reconstruction method:

You have two lists, preorder and postorder traversed node lists. Call these R (pRe) and O (pOst).

- The first element of R is the root node. Remove it from R
- Remove the last element from O and check that it's the same root node (should be)
- Now check the first element of R, it's the root of the leftmost subtree
- Find the same node from O; let's say it's the *k*th node on O
- Now the leftmost subtree has *k* nodes on it; take the first *k* nodes from both lists R and O and **recursively execute this algorithm** to reconstruct the leftmost subtree
- Continue with the remaining part of R and O, iterating this, to reconstruct the remaining subtrees of the root node

Pseudocode - recursive procedure that returns the tree. Input: the two traversal lists r = preorder, o = postorder

```
def mktree(r, o):
  l = len(r)
  assert l == len(o)
  root = r[0]
  assert root == o[l - 1]
  if l == 1:
     return mknode(root)
  else:
     myroot = mknode(root)
     r = r[1:l]     # sublist that excludes first element 
     o = o[0:l-1]   # sublist that excludes last element
     while len(r) > 0: # iterate and construct subtrees
       first = r[0]
       lim = -1
       for i in 0..l - 1:
         if o[i] == first:
            lim = i + 1
            break
       assert lim != -1
       myroot.add_rightmost_child(mktree(r[0:lim], o[0:lim])
       r = r[lim:len(r)] # sublist from lim until end of list
       o = o[lim:len(o)] # sublist from lim until end of list
     return myroot
```

Here's an example of how it works:

Original tree:

```
            1
          / | \
         2  3  4
        /     / \
       5      6  7
```

Preorder traversal ("top-down depth-first"): 1 2 5 3 4 6 7

Postorder traversal ("bottom-up"): 5 2 3 6 7 4 1

Algorithm execution:

```
mktree(1253467, 5236741)
    myroot = 1
    r = 253467, o = 523674
    loc = 1 (location of '2' in o)
         mktree(25, 52)
              myroot = 2
              mktree(5, 5) -> returns singleton tree 5
         list exhausted -> returns tree 2[5] (5 only child of 2)
    add 2[5] to myroot as right child, tree at myroot 1[2[5]]
    r = 3467, o = 3674 (stripped away "25" that was processed)
    loc = 0 (location of '3' in o)
         mktree(3, 3) returns singleton tree 3
    add 3 to myroot as right child, tree at myroot 1[2[5], 3]
    r = 467, o = 674 (stripped away "3" that was processed)
    loc = 2 (location of '4' in o)
         mktree(467, 674)
              myroot = 4
              r = 67, o = 67
              (recursive calls return first singleton 6, then 7)
              returns tree 4[6,7]
    add 4[6,7] to myroot as right child, tree at myroot 1[2[5],3,4[6,7]]
    list exhausted, return tree
```

As a result, the original tree was reconstructed.

For reference, here definition of preorder and postorder traversals in pseudocode:

```
 def preorder(t):
     l = [root_node(t)]     # BEFORE recursion = PREorder
     for c in t.children(): # in left to right order
         l.append(preorder(c))
     return l

 def postorder(t):
     l = []
     for c in t.children(): # in left to right order
         l.append(postorder(c))
     l.append(root_node(t)) # AFTER recursion = POSTorder
     return l
```

Comment: Can you perhaps give a pseudocode example? I'm having trouble understanding what you presented.

Comment: Ok, added pseudocode and simulation by hand on an example tree